# HDB table comparision

Tags: kdb

Posting this question in **Q&A-style**.

Why boolean match between 2 identical tables (one of them is selected from HDB) generate `0b` rather than `1b`?

```
q)trade:trade2:`sym`time xasc ([] sym:5?`apple`google;time:5?.z.t;price:100+5?1.)

q).Q.dpft[`:tmp;.z.d-1;`sym;`trade]
`trade
```

Load the HDB

```
\l tmp/
q)hist:select from trade where date=.z.d-1
q)hist
date       sym    time         price   
---------------------------------------
2018.04.23 apple  02:31:39.330 100.2392
2018.04.23 apple  04:25:17.604 100.1508
2018.04.23 apple  07:57:14.764 100.2782
2018.04.23 google 02:59:16.636 100.1567
2018.04.23 google 14:35:31.860 100.9785

q)(`date xcols update date:.z.d-1 from trade2)
date       sym    time         price   
---------------------------------------
2018.04.23 apple  02:31:39.330 100.2392
2018.04.23 apple  04:25:17.604 100.1508
2018.04.23 apple  07:57:14.764 100.2782
2018.04.23 google 02:59:16.636 100.1567
2018.04.23 google 14:35:31.860 100.9785
```

Table comparison generates false(`0b`)

```
q)(`date xcols update date:.z.d-1 from trade2)~hist
0b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mismatch is due to the type of `sym` column (`20h`) of the table selected from HDB.

```
\l tmp/
q)hist:select from trade where date=.z.d-1
q)type exec sym from hist
20h
q)type exec sym from trade2
11h
q)type exec value sym from hist
11h
```

Though it looks exactly like symbol but has a **new** type `20h`, something similar to the following [(from Kx wiki)](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Datatypes)

```
q)type `city$10?city:`london`paris`rome
21h
```

Using `value` with `sym` to get the desired result:

```
q)(`date xcols update date:.z.d-1 from trade2)~update value sym from hist
1b
```